# Force missing fields in jsonpath_ng

Tags: python, jsonpath

**When parsing JSON objects using [`jsonpath_ng`](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng), is there a way to force missing fields to return None?** To clarify, I'm not looking for how to do this using any other method, just using `jsonpath_ng` (or other Python `JSONPath` parsers).

The idea is that I want the final lists to be of the same length. Here is a very simple example, my actual use case requires using some kind of programmatic parsing:

```
from jsonpath_ng import parse

data = {
    'source': 'api',
    'data': {
        'records': [
            {
                'id': '1',
                'value': 10
            },
            {
                'id': '2'
            },
            {
                'id': '3',
                'value': 30
            },
            
        ]
    }
}

# Default behavior
ids = parse('$.data.records[*].id').find(data)
values = parse('$.data.records[*].value').find(data)
print([
    (i.value, j.value)
    for i, j in zip(ids, values)
])

# using the ``jsonpath.auto_id_field`` setting seems to target similar issue,
# but not exactly what I need:
jsonpath.auto_id_field = 'values'  # this seems to 
ids = parse('$.data.records[*].id').find(data)
values = parse('$.data.records[*].value').find(data)

print('Using jsonpath.auto_id_field = "value"')
print([
    (i.value, j.value)
    for i, j in zip(ids, values)
])
```

Output:

```
[('1', 10), ('2', 30)]

Using jsonpath.auto_id_field = 'value'
[('1', 'data.records.10'), ('2', 'data.records.[1]'), ('3', 'data.records.30')]
```

Which is obviously incorrect. Desired output:

```
[('1', 10), ('2', None), ('3', 30)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Issue with the Example** (based on Question [revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68624062/5))

You collect 3 ids and 2 values with `parse(json_path).find(value)` and then use the built-in function `zip(*iterables)`.

According to [`zip(*iterables)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. **The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.**

Therefore, the third id is not considered. In addition, because of the missing value, you have wrong id/value pairs.

---

**Answer to Question** (based on Question [revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68624062/5))

Looks like `jsonpath_ng` does not provide the functionality defaulting to null. There is actually a similar [Github issue](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/issues/49).

However, you could do something like that:

```py
records = parse("$.data.records[*]").find(data)
result = [
    (pair.value.get("id"), pair.value.get("value", None)) for pair in records
]
# [('1', 10), ('3', None), ('2', 20)]
```

---

**Alternative [`jsonpath-python`](https://github.com/zhangxianbing/jsonpath-python)**

```py
from jsonpath import JSONPath

result = JSONPath("$.data.records[*].(id,value)").parse(data)
# [{'id': '1', 'value': 10}, {'id': '3', 'value': None}, {'id': '2', 'value': 20}]

result = [(record["id"], record["value"]) for record in result]
# [('1', 10), ('3', None), ('2', 20)]
```

---

**Alternative [`JMESPath`](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py)**

It's not JSONPath... but you could also use [`JMESPath`](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) (see also [here](https://jmespath.org)):

```py
import jmespath

result = jmespath.search("data.records[*].[id, value]", data)
# [['1', 10], ['3', None], ['2', 20]]
```

Comment: I'm using `zip` to demo the problem. In my application, I using Pandas which is causing an error.

Comment: Your comment about jsonpath_ng was very helpful. That is the kind of information I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Since you added "or other Python JSONPath parsers", I extended my answer with examples using `jsonpath-python` and `JMESPath`...

Answer (score 0):

I think that using jsonpath_ng is overkill for this. Based on your sample data, this will suffice:-

```
data = {
    'source': 'api',
    'data': {
        'records': [
            {
                'id': '1',
                'value': 10
            },
            {
                'id': '2',
                'value': 20
            },
            {
                'id': '3'
            },

        ]
    }
}

mylist = []

for _r in data['data']['records']:
    _id = _r.get('id')
    _value = _r.get('value')
    mylist.append((_id, _value))

print(mylist)
```

Comment: This is just a simple example for demo ... the actual use case requires parsing to be done programmatically.

Comment: Well, if my answer isn't programmatic then I don't know what is